# Volume of two spheres

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, spheres

We have two spheres.

Sphere 1: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ (right)

Sphere 2: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2y$ (left)

I have to calculate the volume, delimited on right by eq1 and left by eq2. What does the exercise mean by left and right? I have no textbook answer.

Comment: For the purpose of solving this problem it doesn't matter, it just a convention which depends on how you see the sphere, it can be up/down , left/right. By the way, you are asking the actual problem or just meaning of left/right?

Comment: Hello, Ajay. Thank you for your answer. I'm asking about the actual problem.

Comment: If the second sphere was $x^2+y^2+z^2=2x$ I could see why one might use the left/right terminology. But not with your actual second sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hskip 1.9 in$[image]

Here is a plot of spheres.
Let $S_1$ be the blue sphere and $S_2$ be red one, given: $$ \begin{align} S_1 :&  x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 1 \\ S_2 : & x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 2y \end{align}$$

On solving $y = 1/2$ , which is the equation of blue plane. As you can see the system is symmetric about the plane, so if one can calculate the smaller red part $T$(which lies in the blue sphere), then the net volume of intersection would be just double of that. In other words, we have to find the volume of sphere $S_1$ for $1>y>1/2$.

$T$ can be subdivided into disks of radius, say $r$ with infinitesimal thickness $dy$
$$ \Rightarrow dV = \pi r^2 dy$$

If $y$ be the distance between centre of sphere and centre of disc,and $R$ be radius of $S_1$ then by pythogoreas: $$r^2 = R^2 - y^2$$ $$ \Rightarrow dV = \pi (R^2 - y^2) dy$$  $$ \Rightarrow V = \int_{1/2}^1 \pi (R^2 - y^2) dy $$

This is the volume of $T$, as stated earllier net volume is $2V$

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Ajay. I still can't understand that T part. I've plotted it in a paper sheet, and I don't seem to get a radius different from 1 for the disks. Or should it be 1/2?

Comment: Disks have variable radius $r$ when the disk almost 1 distance away from centre of sphere(almost at the surface of the sphere) it would be 0, as $r^2 = R^2 - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0$, for "edge". When the disc lies in the plane $y = 1/2$, $r^2 = 1 - 1/4 = 3/4$. So $r \in ( \sqrt(3) / 2 , 0)$

Comment: You got that now?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sphere 1 has the center at the origin. The equation of sphere 2 can be written as $$x^2+y^2+z^2=2y\\x^2+y^2-2y+z^2=0\\x^2+y^2-2y+1+z^2=1\\x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1$$
The last is the equation of the sphere with the center at $y=1$

Comment: Centre at $(0,1,0)$ surely?

Comment: Correct. The $x$ and &z& coordinates of the center are &0&, same as the other sphere. Sorry for the inexact statement.